# Android upload image to WCF service "Parameter is not valid."

Tags: android, wcf

Selecting an image from gallery, I am able to upload a stream, but get the error "Parameter is not valid." when trying to convert to image in WCF.

Android code creates connection to REST service and uploads image as Byte[]:

```java
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

  if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
    Uri targetUri = data.getData();

    Bitmap bitmap;
    try {
      bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(targetUri));
      ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

      bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 6, out);

      DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

      byte[] sendData = out.toByteArray();

      HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost("http://www.thehost.dk/MobileService/Service.svc/uploadpicture/");
      ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(sendData, "picture.jpg");
      MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
      reqEntity.addPart("image", bab);
      postRequest.setEntity(reqEntity);
      httpClient.execute(postRequest);
```

WCF C# code receives stream and tries to convert to an image, but receives error:

```cs
    public void UploadPicture(Stream imageData)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] image = StreamToBytes(imageData);

            ImageConverter imageConverter = new ImageConverter();
            Image img = imageConverter.ConvertFrom(image) as Image; <-- Exception happens here

            SaveImage(img);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    private byte[] StreamToBytes(Stream stream)
    {
        byte[] output = new byte[0];
        byte[] stream_array = new byte[0];
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;

        while ((read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            stream_array = new byte[output.Length + read];
            output.CopyTo(stream_array, 0);
            Array.Copy(buffer, 0, stream_array, output.Length, read);
            output = stream_array;
        }

        return output;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show us your interface class in WCF ?

Comment: Do you use  `[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "", Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]`, that kind of method in WCF interface ?

Comment: Could you please tell me from where can i get these classes-ByteArrayBody and MultipartEntity??

Answer (score 5):

I would like to first explain why the issue occurred first and then give you the solution:
Try this experiment on your code. Instead of the following code which you have used, replace it with the code which is below that:

```
       public void UploadPicture(Stream imageData)
       {
           try
           {
               byte[] image = StreamToBytes(imageData);
               ImageConverter imageConverter = new ImageConverter();
               Image img = imageConverter.ConvertFrom(image) as Image;
               SaveImage(img);
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               Log(ex.ToString());
           }
       }
```

replace with,

```
    public void UploadPicture (Stream imageData)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[10000];
            imagedata.Read(buffer, 0, 10000);
            FileStream f = new FileStream("D:\\FileUpload\\SubjectFront.JPG", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
            f.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            f.Close();
            imagedata.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        } 
    }
```

This code executes without any exception (I believe) and you would find the image file in the “saved” path. Notice the file which is created in your D:\FileUpload. The size of the file is much larger than the size of the file sent by your android code(i.e. if you have not compressed it). Try opening this file with any image editor and it would open as a corrupted file (you would not be able to see the image).

Now open the file with notepad. One could see that along with the garbled binary data, there is also some text available. Example: -- Content-Disposition: form-data;….. blah blah. This text is the culprit for your “Parameter is not valid” exception. While using Multipart in java, it adds this text and send it along the image data which is converted to byte stream. I’m not sure why it does that. 
Now, remove any human readable text and save the file. Open the file in any image editor and viola, there is your image.

Now, the solution lies in to write a code to remove this text from the stream which is received by the WCF method. I found a very beautiful parser written(Thanks to Anthony) which does the job efficiently. You can find it here (http://multipartparser.codeplex.com/). Just add this .cs file to your project and do something like below.

```
    public string UploadPicture (Stream imagedata)
    {
        MultipartParser parser = new MultipartParser(imagedata);

        if (parser.Success)
        {
            string fileName = parser.Filename;
            string contentType = parser.ContentType;
            byte[] fileContent = parser.FileContents;
            System.Drawing.Image image = byteArrayToImage(fileContent);
            image.Save("D:\\FileUpload\\" + fileName);
            return "Success !!!";
         }
         else
         {
            return "Exception!!!";
         }
   }
```

The implementation of byteArrayToImage is as follows:

```
public System.Drawing.Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
    System.Drawing.Image returnImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
    return returnImage;
}
```

Hope it has helped…