# Upload image from Android to WCF C # /. NET

Tags: c#, android, .net, web-services, wcf-rest

Good morning, I need to send an image that is in the Memory Card from the unit to a webservice that I did in wcf / C # in order, do not know much C # was a requirement here the company, I even can send a Strem for WCF but it'm having trouble to convert and transform into a Bitmap or something.

Follow my android code that makes the post image in wcf:

```
/**
 * 
 * Método responsável por enviar imagem para o servidor
 *
 * @param String caminho
 * @author Douglas Costa <douglas.cst90@gmail.com.br>
 * @since 01/07/2013 18:27:49
 * @version 1.0
 */
public static void upload(String caminho){

    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.205:8070/Service/uploadImagem");
    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();

    File file = new File(caminho);
    //This is the new shit to deal with MIME
    MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
    entity.addPart("image", new FileBody(file, "image/jpeg"));
    httppost.setEntity(entity);

    try {
        String responseString = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And here is my post on WCF method in C # that receives the stream from the image:

```
/// Método POST que recebe um Stream do Android
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="imagem"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "uploadImagem")]
    public Bitmap uploadImagem(Stream imagem)
    {

        try
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                int read;
                while ((read = imagem.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
                buffer = ms.ToArray();
            }

            using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                mStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(mStream);
                return bm;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Already tried several ways to convert the stream, also do not know if the way I'm sending is correct, but I have a similar method that works but in a JAVA webservice.

Appreciate if someone can help me with C #.

sorry for english errors, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these 3 whether these can help you..

- http://www.jarredcapellman.com/2012/2/8/getting-a-picture-from-android-to-a-wcf-service
- [POSTing image from Android to WCF Rest Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542247/posting-image-from-android-to-wcf-rest-service)
- [Android upload image to WCF service "Parameter is not valid."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285226/android-upload-image-to-wcf-service-parameter-is-not-valid)